# There is two AutoComplete function of jQuery and passing parameter from result of one autocomplete function to another autocomplete function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

hi i am trying to pass parameter from result of one autocomplete function to another autocomplete by setting the value from result of first autocomplete function into hiddenField And Passing the parameter value to second autocomplete function using that hiddenField but its value is showing NaN
Please suggest

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hdnQuality_Id = '<%=hdnFabric_Qualityid.ClientID %>';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var fabric_Quality_id;
       
        $("input[type=text].auto-fabricname").autocomplete("/Webservices/iKandiService.asmx/SuggestFabricNameByName1", { dataType: "xml", datakey: "string", max: 100, "width": "220px" });
        $("input[type=text].auto-fabricname", "#main_content").result(function () { if ($(this).val().length === 1) { $(this).val(''); } });


        $("input[type=text].auto-fabricname").result(function () {
            debugger;

            mys = $(this).val().split('$');
            if (!mys[1]) {

                return false;

            }

            mys2 = mys[1].split('**');


            $(this).val(mys2[0]);
            fabric_Quality_id = mys2[1];
            $("#" + hdnQuality_Id).val(fabric_Quality_id)


        });

        $("input[type=text].auto-color").autocomplete("/Webservices/iKandiService.asmx/SuggestColorPrintName", { dataType: "xml", datakey: "string", max: 100, "width": "220px", extraParams:
                    {
                        Qualityid: parseInt($('#ctl00_cph_main_content_hdnFabric_Qualityid').val())
                    }
        });
        $("input[type=text].auto-color").result(function () {
            debugger;
            var col = $(this).val().split('**');
            $(this).val(col[1]);
            alert($('#<%=hdnFabric_Qualityid.ClientID %>').val());

        });

    });
```

Comment: you missed the '#' in the first line of you code?did you inspect your code., whether a console is showing any error on form load?

Comment: no sir ,since i am only receiving id from first line of code there for there is   no error on console regarding this line of code

Comment: what line are you getting the error NaN?

Comment: Sir in this line  Qualityid:parseInt($('#ctl00_cph_main_content_hdnFabric_Qualityid').val())  Where i am passing Quality id in second autocomplete Using hidden field there i am getting NaN value in  the hidden field

Comment: why are you using 'ctl00_cph_main_content_hdnFabric_Qualityid' instead of ' $("#" + hdnQuality_Id).val() or fabric_Quality_id?.does any other variables holds the values or its also NaN? ., This value changes to system to system 'ctl00_cph_main_content_hdnFabric_Qualityid', dont use it if you are going to use it in your local system only. what is the value before parseInt value(because you are spliting and assing in hiddenval)? check the actual value from the first autocomplete ?

Comment: Sir actual value form last autocompleted is coming correct checked it in alert also but at the time of passing parameter it is showing NaN , i have tried this  $("#" + hdnQuality_Id).val() also but the same result .

Comment: inspect and watch tag in the debugger for the control hidden field values ., find out where it is getting NaN